# Conflict between devices in call log if we have the same Apple ID

Tags: iphone, ios, phone.app

I have iOS 9.0.2 on an iPhone 5s and my wife has an iPhone 6 with the same iOS version. We have the same Apple ID and we have issue after upgrading the two call logs are the same now. If she has a call I will find it in my log.

Comment: Are you using separate iCloud accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is part of iCloud which synchronises features across multiple devices which use the same primary Apple ID. If you don't wish this to synchronise, change your primary Apple ID on one of the devices.

Comment: Do you mean create another Apple ID in others devices ? but this is new issue after upgrading the new version , I have four devices in the same Apple ID , this issue in two devices only

Comment: Apple never meant 2 people to share the same ID. One ID is supposed to do what you are seeing, seamlessly handoff synchronised data between all devices using that ID. If you need shared apps/music etc use [Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060)  instead.

Comment: If I need to deactivate this feature , how can I will do ?

Comment: @Abdelhamid *"If you don't wish this to synchronise, change your primary Apple ID on one of the devices."*